# Ramnode was hacked SolusVM zero day exploit (what should I customer do?)

Tags: security, exploit

So, ramnode was compromised, some kid used zero day exploit to gain access and rm -rf.

I'm really happy how ramnode team handled situation, finally my VPS was restored and it is back online.

I've a question, and I need someone with experience to help me out :)

1. I had root login/account disabled and used SSH keys to login. Ramnode asked us to change root password, but since I used keys should I change keys? or am I fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very localized question, but I would *definitely* re-generate SSH keys.